# Encode a AWS Cognito User ID into a valid ObjectId in python and Decode it back

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, amazon-cognito

I want to encode a AWS Cognito user id into a valid ObjectId which can be used in MongoDB as a document ID so that each users Document can be identified by the user's user id.

> A valid ObjectId must be a 12-byte input or a 24-character hex string

Here is a sample AWS Cognito User ID (str):

> b5bb610b-de5a-480e-9363-84905ae33d23

I tried converting the Cognito user id into bytes, as well as into hex but it does not satisfy the requirement. Here is the code

```
import bson
u = "b5bb610b-de5a-480e-9363-84905ae33d23"
bson.ObjectId(u.encode("utf-8"))
bson.ObjectId(u.encode("utf-8").hex())
```

If sha224 is used as shown below,

```
from hashlib import sha224
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
hasher = sha224()
cognito_id = cognito_id.encode("utf-8")
prefix = cognito_id[:6]
hasher.update(cognito_id)
hashed = hasher.digest()
partial_hash = hashed[:9]
mongo_id = prefix+partial_hash
mongo_id = ObjectId(str(mongo_id))
```

All of them throw the error mentioning the requirement mentioned above.

Using hex string does the encoding job,

```
from hashlib import sha224
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
hasher = sha224()
cognito_id = cognito_id.encode("utf-8")
prefix = cognito_id.hex()[:6]
hasher.update(cognito_id)
hashed = hasher.hexdigest()[:18]
mongo_id = prefix + hashed
mongo_id = ObjectId(mongo_id)
```

But I cannot decode it back. I can get only the first 6 characters of Cognito Id by

```
cognito_prefix = str(mongo_id)[:6]
```

> There will be a situation where I will need the whole Cognito ID derived from the mongo Object Id.

I need to encode the Cognito user id into a valid Object Id which can be stored in mongoDB, as well as decode it back.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) to compute `sha224` of the Cognito ID.
Feed the first 12 bytes to Mongo as the unique document ID.

Downside of that approach would be that
the sort order for JOINs becomes randomized,
and you can only learn anything about the original Cognito ID
after fetching the Mongo document.
To remedy that you might choose to make a 3 / 9 split.
With your example ID,
you might copy the three bytes 0xb5 0xbb 0x61
verbatim as the prefix of the document ID,
then append the initial nine bytes of the `sha224` result
to uniquify.

Comment: It is not working. I have updated the question mentioning the implementation that you suggested. Hex Digest is working.